# Manually trigger NavigationThemeTransition in Windows Phone WinRT/Universal app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone

In my application I use a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Content">
    <ContentControl.ContentTransitions>
        <NavigationThemeTransition />
    </ContentControl.ContentTransitions>
</ContentControl>
```

The problem is that the `NavigationThemeTransition` is not triggered when changing the `Content` property of the `ContentControl`. I think this is because it is only triggered in a `Frame` control when calling the `Navigate()` method.

I need this transition to be run when the `Content` of the `ContentControl` changes...

Is there a way to trigger the navigation-in and navigation-out animation manually?

Or is there some visual state to which the control can got to run the animation?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this You would be needed to have Custom Transition for the Control shown here [custom transitions](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--custom-transitions) and for implementing Transition Effects in coding you can have Reference from here [Using Page Transitions via Code](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide)

Comment: This is about a WP8 Universal App (not silverlight) and i need to start the "official" animation not a custom one...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a `Frame` control instead of a `ContentControl`. If that doesn't work - you'd need to create a custom control that has a `Frame` in its template and when its content change happens - it would navigate to a new page to display the new content.

I haven't seen a way to trigger the built-in transitions other than invoking an action that these transitions were created for. Personally - I would rather create my own transition than hack around to invoke the built-in one. You should be able to create one that looks exactly the same as the built-in one.

Comment: The whole idea is to completely reimplement the Frame control... so this is not an option. The idea is to simulate the Frame control...

Comment: Funny how I've [done that too](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs), but I didn't care about built-in transitions since one of the reasons for reimplementing it was to be able to build my own transitions.

Comment: Yes, for win8 its a good solution but i need the original transition for the windows phone winrt part... Its needed there